# Error in setBackgroundResources

Tags: java, android

So I got this code here...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);

    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            startBtn.setClickable(false);
            String[] splited=h.split(",");





        for(String k : splited){
            findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + k, "id",      getPackageName())).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_blink);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + k, "id", getPackageName())).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button); 
        }

        }
    });
```

}
The purpose is to change the background of the button, everything seems fine but when I run this on android, the application just pauses and then resumes after the total seconds programmed in the Thread.sleep.

Anything wrong here?

Also, the activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/toggle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom|center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:text="@string/Clear" >
</Button>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            style="@style/toggle"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textOff=" "
            android:textOn=" " />

    </FrameLayout>

    <Space
        style="@style/space"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
            style="@style/toggle"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textOff=" "
            android:textOn=" " />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Space
        style="@style/space"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
            style="@style/toggle"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textOff=" "
            android:textOn=" " />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Space
        style="@style/space"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton4"
            style="@style/toggle"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textOff=" "
            android:textOn=" " />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:gravity="bottom|center" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton5"
            style="@style/toggle"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textOff=" "
            android:textOn=" " />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Space style="@style/space" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton6"
            style="@style/toggle"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textOff=" "
            android:textOn=" " />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Space style="@style/space" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton7"
            style="@style/toggle"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textOff=" "
            android:textOn=" " />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@drawable/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="@string/Start"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</GridLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why use `getResources` just to find the iD?? also post the activity_main.xml

Comment: added the activity_main.xml :)
also, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use thread.sleep you are actually sleeping the ui thread and therefore it may cause issues trying to change any ui elements will not take affect. Try using a delayed handler.

```
Handler handler=new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
           findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + k, "id",            getPackageName())).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button); 

        handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
```

Comment: what if I want to add an action (change the background again) after the delayed?

Comment: Set it to change depending on the action that you want to cause it. The handler will not affect this code.